# What does the "disabled" attribute of addUniqueConstraint mean in Liquibase?

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am adding a unique constraint to a MySQL table using liquibase. In this [Liquibase official document page](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_unique_constraint.html), there is an attribute named "disabled". I googled a lot and cannot find anything about it. Could anyone help?

Note that the example in the document page says that this liquibase script

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="addUniqueConstraint-example">
<addUniqueConstraint catalogName="cat"
        columnNames="id, name"
        constraintName="const_name"
        deferrable="true"
        disabled="true"
        initiallyDeferred="true"
        schemaName="public"
        tableName="person"
        tablespace="A String"/>
</changeSet>
```

will generate this sql for MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE cat.person ADD CONSTRAINT const_name UNIQUE (id,
name);
```

so I wonder what will happen if I change the "disabled" in the script to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think nothing will happen when you use mySQL because it does not support this.

`DISABLE` seems to be only used when working with Oracle databases.

I determined this by finding this class on github in the liquibase sources: [AddUniqueConstraintGenerator](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/a468cfc7a3769cd8b1264553811a4f562d6c6037/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/sqlgenerator/core/AddUniqueConstraintGenerator.java)

Checkout the `generateSql` method. There `DISABLE` is only used on Oracle DBs.

And quickly checking on Oracles syntax... seems like Oracle does support this as a way to enable or disable a constraint.